# django time display by using timesince

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-timezone

I am using the Django template filter tag timesince.
it displays well time Greater than one minute. But when is less than one minute it showing **`0 minutes ago`**
i want it to be in seconds

here is my code

```
<p>{{ article.article_published_date| timesince | upto :',' }} ago</p>
```

I need ouput as **20seconds ago** is there any way to display 
The template tag am using now is

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def upto(value, delimiter=None):
    return (value.split(delimiter)[0])
upto.is_safe = True
```

any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to write your own [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/) as [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) docs state

> Minutes is the smallest unit used, and “0 minutes” will be returned
> for any date that is in the future relative to the comparison point.

Source of [timesince](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/timesince.py)

Comment: I am new to django. why don't you example template tag code to display return seconds

Comment: i have one template tag excisting i will provide that in question

Comment: I have answered your question with clear documentation that timesince does not have seconds also gave you approach where you should look next . You should write it, it is your job/hobby you misrepresent what this site is for ,check out this link ( https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ ).